# Loading and parsing .ini file inside or from a Gruntfile

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, ini

- Gruntfile.js is located at `project root/Gruntfile.js`
- asset_compress.ini is located at `project root/app/Config/asset_compress.ini`
- Tests are written using Jasmine, and the specs all locate in `project root/tests/**/*`

The following is a stripped-down Gruntfile. If you need more, feel free to ask:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    grunt.initConfig({
        jasmine: {
            test: {
                src: [
                    'node_modules/jasmine-expect/dist/jasmine-matchers.js',
                    'app/webroot/js/libraries/jquery-2.0.js',
                    'app/webroot/js/api/ClassUtility.js',
                    'app/webroot/js/api/**/*.js'
                ],
                options: {
                    log: true,
                    specs: [
                        'tests/app/webroot/js/api/ClassUtility.spec.js',
                        'tests/**/*.spec.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

`ClassUtility` (and its specification) need to be loaded before any other part of the API, because it contains everything all other "classes" rely on. This is why it's declared specifically above all other api classes.

However, I have many(!) dependencies and many other files that I need, and they're all present in a (rather large) `asset_compress.ini`. Ideally, I would want to keep that single ini file as the only list and have my Gruntfile read from that list to know what source files it should load.

TLDR:
How would I configure my Gruntfile with the content of my ini file?

Comment: Use [ini-parser](https://github.com/shockie/node-iniparser) to read the ini file and create grunt's config from it.

Comment: Thank you! The library is quite outdated, but it got me going on the solution!

Comment: Didn't even notice! I used it just last week. I found the ini format to be convenient, regardless of its _uncoolness_

Comment: @bfred.it I created my own parser, I will put the link in an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bfred.it suggested, there were plenty of node packages that can parse .ini files. However, none of them worked the way I wanted them to work so I decided to create my own.

The source code, documentation, instructions and anything else you may desire can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/skelware/node-file-parser/

Feel free to request features on its issue tracker!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to load and parse an ini file in node:
First install on command line:

```
npm install parse-ini
```

Then in the code:

```
var iniParser = require('parse-ini');
var parsedIni = iniParser.parse('yourfile.ini');
// job done, you can use results in parsedIni:
console.log(parsedIni.sectionName.variableName);
console.log(parsedIni.variableWithoutSectionName);
```